# How to merge a flat array and a multidim array based on indexes and sum subarray column values?

Tags: php, arrays, sum, grouping

There are two arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value1"
];

$arr2 = [
    ["key_1" => "5", "key_2" => "10"],   // relates to Value1
    ["key_1" => "2", "key_2" => "4"],    // relates to Value2
    ["key_1" => "50", "key_2" => "100"]  // relates to Value1
];
```

I cannot simply `combine` the two arrays because the duplicated values in `$arr1` will lead to overwritten data from `$arr2`.

The behavior that I need is for subarray data to be added if a value from `$arr1` is encountered more than once.

I tried to find all sorts of folding options while searching the web, but I could find anything that was right.

I need this output from the sample input arrays:

```
array (
  'Value1' => 
  array (
    'key_1' => 55,
    'key_2' => 110,
  ),
  'Value2' => 
  array (
    'key_1' => '2',
    'key_2' => '4',
  ),
)
```

I've tried to write a solution, but I'm not really sure how to tackle the problem.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (isset($bal[$item['bonus_name']])) {
        //Here I don't know how to sum a new one to the repetition?
    } else {
        $bal[$item['bonus_name']] = $item['bonus_count'];
    }          
}
```

Whatever I try, there's no way to sum a repetitive array of elements.  I need some help.

Comment: I apologize for my English. I want the SUM of the values, not the addition.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should at least specify the programmation language you want to use

Comment: It makes rather little sense, to look at the existing array functions, for a rather special use case like this. The logic needed here is pretty trivial to write yourself, you loop over the first array, the values become your top-level keys in the result array. So you simply check if there already is an entry in the result array for the current ValueX/key_Y combination - if so, you _add_ the current value to it, otherwise you _set_ it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I have added to the top how I try to solve the problem and where I have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the first array to declare the index -> group relationship.

Check if the currently encountered group is unique to the output array.  If so, push the entire subarray from the corresponding index in the second array into the output array as the initial values of the group.

If the group is encountered more than once, add each column value to the related amount in the group's subarray.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PNEbY))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $index => $group) {
    if (!isset($result[$group])) {
        $result[$group] = $arr2[$index];
    } else {
        foreach ($arr2[$index] as $key => $value) {
            $result[$group][$key] += $value;
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Yes, and again, yes! That's exactly what I need, thank you very much! I'm going to deal with the logic of the script, I have a big gap in it).